# Avoid the "no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible" warning in Eclipse for multiple Java versions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I know that there are already a lot of questions about this warning, but my question is a little bit different. I understand that I can use this configuration in my `pom.xml` to fix it

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This gets rid of the warning, but only if I have Java 7 installed and configured in Eclipse. If for example I only have Java 8, I still see the warning unless I change the version in the configuration above to 1.8:

> Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.7. There are no
>   JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this
>   environment.

My project is compatible with Java 7, 8, 9 and 10. What I want to achieve is to avoid this warning if any of these versions of Java is installed without changing the version in my `pom.xml` to match the currently installed Java version every time. Something to tell Eclipse that Java 7 or anything above is good.

The project still compiles and works fine with the warning, it's just distracting as it marks the project as having issues. **I know that I can hide this type of warnings in Eclipse settings, but is there a way to get rid of it by only using some configuration in `pom.xml`?**

Comment: Unless you **actually have** the 1.7 libraries to compile against when you're targeting 1.7 runtimes, it's a valid warning.

Comment: @nitind I don't have the intention to target some specific version, the default target would work fine for me. The only reason I added the above configuration is to avoid the warning (at least for cases when Java 7 is installed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse uses the value `<target>1.7</target>` to decide which execution environment to include in the build path, as part of its Maven integration.

The execution environments are mapped to JREs **installed in Eclipse** (i.e. referenced in `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`).

The mapping itself is configured in `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Runtime Environments`. Eclipse will automatically match an execution environment (e.g. `JavaSE-1.7`) to an installed JRE (e.g. `jdk1.7.0_80`). If there is no exact match for the execution environment specified in your project, it will give you a warning like the one you're getting.

Therefore, to get rid of the warning, you must either:

- Install the Java version that is an exact match for your `<target>` (i.e. `jdk1.7`) **and add it under `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Runtime Environments`**
- Configure the Java version in your pom to one for which there is an exact match

> My project is compatible with Java 7, 8, 9 and 10. What I want to achieve is to avoid this warning if any of these versions of Java is installed

When configuring the execution environment to use, Eclipse only cares for the `<target>` value. You need to make sure that there is a JRE **installed in Eclipse** whose version is a perfect match for the value of that property. Otherwise, the warning will not go away, period.

> I don't have the intention to target some specific version, the default target would work fine for me.

No, it wouldn't, because the default target is 1.5. Target configuration is a non-optional configuration property, there is no 'target everything' option.

You could remove the Maven-configured execution environment from the build path and add a JRE directly (`project properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add library... > JRE System Library > Alternate JRE`). This will also make the warning go away, but it will be back as soon as you run Maven project update. Such a configuration shouldn't really be used, as it ties your project to a specific installation of Java on your machine.